# Binding with object in Windows forms designer

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, bindingsource

I am trying to bind a list in my namespace to BindingSource through designer. I know how to bind a list in code behind but I would also like to know if it is possible to do the same in designer.

Using the "Data Source Configuration Wizard", I have selected "Object" but it shows only namespace and classes.

[image]

I choose a class with List and clicked Finish.
[image]

This is the code generated in designer after choosing the class name

```
this.bindingSource1.DataSource = typeof(Template.Form3);
```

It looks like windows forms does not have support for binding a list in designer. I am not sure this is the right method or windows forms does not support it. If windows forms have no support for binding to an object, can anyone explain the reason?

**Edit**:
I tried the suggestion in answer to choose a data member, but it does not bind the binding source with actual data in List. Now designer code looks like

```
this.bindingSource1.DataMember = "data";
this.bindingSource1.DataSource = typeof(Template.Form3);
```

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to **rebuild** your solution, then any public class will be visible in the dropdown list to choose the datasource type from.

Then from the designer, click the `binding source` (bottom of screen) `=> Properties => DataMember =>` Select `Property` in your class to bind to (A List or Collection)

**Edit:**

Binding through the designer allows **generation of columns at Design time**, but it seems that you need to set the BindingSource's Data at runtime.

Since the bind object can't be static memeber but instance member.

```
private void bindingForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myDataSourceBindingSource.DataSource = (new  myDataSource()).MyDataSourceList;
}
```

**Designer:**

```
// 
// colADataGridViewTextBoxColumn
// 
this.colADataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "ColA";
this.colADataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "ColA";
this.colADataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "colADataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
// 
// myDataSourceBindingSource
// 
this.myDataSourceBindingSource.DataMember = "MyDataSourceList";
this.myDataSourceBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(myNameSpace.myDataSource);
```

**Class:**

```
public class myDataSource
{
    public BindingList<myData> MyDataSourceList
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<myData>()
            {
                new myData() { ColA = "A" },
                new myData() { ColA = "B" }
            };

            return new BindingList<myData>(list);
        }
    }
}

public class myData
{
    public string ColA { set; get; }
}
```

I don't know if this makes sense for you, but this is how it works in Windows Forms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried your suggestion but data is not bound to the binding source. Now designer generated code looks like this.bindingSource.DataMember = "data";
            this.bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Template.Form3);

Comment: I can understand why it's not working. Data source is actually a type instead of an object. If it is an object, your suggestion will work. Since designer binds a type, I don't think it is possible to bind with an object in designer

Comment: Can you show you "Data" Property which holds the datasource and how you're adding data to it ?

Comment: Data is a property of type BindingList in class Form3. For testing purpose I'm adding 10 data randomly.

Comment: Is it working for you? If yes, pls share your designer generated code in answer.

Comment: Thanks, I know this approach. So windows forms does not provide direct support.